# Hidden file in my training dataset which makes tensorflow return "Unknown image file format. One of JPEG, PNG, GIF, BMP required."

Tags: python, file, operating-system, tensorflow2.0, hidden-files

I have tensorflow model and during the first portions of training the first epoch it works until it reaches about the midpoint (735/2201 [=========>....................]) and then it returns the error in the title.

First I made a script to remove all the files in that directory which dont end with a .jpg but nothing changed.

```
import os
for file in os.listdir(path):
    if not file.endswith('.jpg'):
        os.remove(os.path.join(path,file))
```

Then I opened my macs bash and listed all the files in the directory to see any hidden files but it was all just jpgs.

EDIT:

Nessuno's answer is correct but you have to iterate over the absolute path and not just the file name, something like this should work

```
import os
import imghdr
#define your path
path = '' 

files = os.listdir(path)


for file in files:
    format = imghdr.what(os.path.join(path, file))
    if format != 'jpeg':
        os.remove(os.path.join(path, file))
```

I ended up removing 5 files which were not jpegs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's some file in your `path` that has the `.jpg` extension but it contains a different file format.

You can use the `imghdr` library (that comes with Python itself: https://docs.python.org/3/library/imghdr.html) and check if the header is equal to `jpeg` and remove the image int that case.

In shorty you can change you script to something like:

```py
import os
import imghdr

for file in os.listdir(path):
    if imghdr.what(file) != 'jpeg':
        os.remove(os.path.join(path, file))
```